# What are invariant closed subspaces of $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ under right shift operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T\colon l^2(\mathbb{Z})\to l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ be right shift operator. I was asked to prove that there are uncountably many $T$-invariant closed subspaces. The only invariant subspaces I can think of is having $0$ in before $n^{th}$ entry. But these only gives me countably many invariant subspaces.

I tried using isomorphism between $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $L^2(S^1)$ and view $T$ as multiplication by $z$ operator but could not progress.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: it is not too difficult to check that if $f \in L^2(S^1)$ is [representable by a function that is] identically zero on some subset $E$ of $\mathbb{T}$, then $T(f)$ will also be identically zero on $E$ [use the picture of $T$ as "multiplication by $z$" here;  the condition that $f$ vanish on some subset of $\mathbb{T}$ is perhaps not so easily seen in the Fourier coefficients of $f$].  Can you use this observation to identify uncountably many invariant subspaces of $T$?

Comment: I need to take $E$ as non-zero measure set else vanishing on measure zero sets does nothing, every function almost does it. Also I need any two sets to not become almost equal i.e., for any two sets $A$ and $B$, $A-B$ or $B-A$ must have non-zero measure, else function vanishing at one set will also almost vanish at other one. Did I get it right?

Comment: You have the right idea.  And note that if you only want to show that there are uncountably many subspaces, it is not necessary to fully answer the general question of when the subspaces corresponding to two subsets $E$ and $E'$ as described above are equal to one another (although you are beginning to do that).  It would be enough to show, for example, that the spaces $E_t$ corresponding to the intervals $[0,t]$, $0 < t < 2 \pi$, are invariant and distinct from one another.